# pycharm Call Tips not work in scrapy

Tags: scrapy, pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VplIi.png)

not show all method for response

pycharm version: PyCharm Community Edition 2016.1

python version: 2.7.1

Comment: Try including more information in the body of the question, not linked. It will help you get more responses.

Answer (score 3):

Pycharm cannot show you autocomplete methods for undefined type values. How could pycharm know that response in this function will be a `scrapy.http.Response` object?

## Python <3.5

For this PyCharm would need an explicit functionality to track whether the project is a scrapy spider and assume that `response` is a `scrapy.http.Response` object which I believe what it does with `django` framework. At the moment this doesn't exist for scrapy.

If you really want autocomplete you can override the response object temporarily:

```
from scrapy.http import Response

def parse(self, response):
    response = response or Response()
    response.  # autocompletes now
    # continue code as you would
```

This will give you autocomplete since pycharm will have a hint now what response might be. It's also shouldn't change your response to an empty object since `response` will never be empty(or in other words `bool(response)` is never False) to fail the first part of the evaluation.

## Python >=3.5

as of python 3.6 type hints can be used:

```
from scrapy.http import Response

def parse(self, response:Response):
    ...
```

Comment: In python3 you can use type hints: `def parse(self, response: Response):` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

Comment: Thanks, this answer was before python 3.5's type hints. I've updated it with type hint mention!